# Classify music according to bpm

Tags: python, pandas, classification, spotipy

I'm looking for a way to correctly classify music starting from bpm. Let me explain: I have a series of songs listened to during different time slots of the same day, for example at 8 am I listen to music that has an average bpm of 140 at 2 pm I have an average of 120bpm. Is there a library in python or a way to say with certainty that at 8 pm I listen to music for example rock and at 2 pm I listen to house music for example? Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to use the page ... I saw from your profile that you are familiar with the spotify APIs, I need some clarification, can you help me?

Comment: An easier solution is to get the artist id from current_user_recently_played() and then get their genres using artists()

Comment: In reference to your answer "An easier solution is to get the artist id from current_user_recently_played () and then get their genres using artists ()" how can I encode it?

Comment: I've finished code that you can use to get the genres of up to 50 tracks you've been listening to. It doesn't do what you asked for jet (to get the genres you listen to around a specific time), but it's a beginning. https://gist.github.com/Ximzend57/90c8242eb2ecc3d3d4c3797a3be8d5cf

Comment: Here is code to store all genre names with their average bpm in a dictionary: https://gist.github.com/Ximzend57/4bc6a3d2bccc7e3204ca35a97ed26305

Answer (score 0):

The details depend on your dataset, but an easy way to begin is to compute the mean BPM of all the songs in each genre, then compare the BPM of a new song to those means, assigning it to the genre with the closest mean. Note that the general approach of detecting genre on the basis of BPM will only work if the genres you listen to don't have similar BPMs.